# powershell : store a specific line in a variable and reuse it

Tags: powershell, variables

i would like to know how can i store in a variable the output of an get-wmiobject specific line

eg:

```
PS C:\Users\gaga> get-wmiobject Win32_Product -Filter "Name like '%team%'" | Sort-Object -Property Name |Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage -AutoSize

IdentifyingNumber                      Name                         LocalPackage                   
-----------------                      ----                         ------------                   
{ABC12345-1234-1234-8936-123456789ABC} Teams Machine-Wide Installer C:\Windows\Installer\523ff8.msi

--> (totaly fictive numbers)
```

i would like to store this :
$var1={ABC12345-1234-1234-8936-123456789ABC}

to reuse it inside this command :

```
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x $var1 /quiet /n" -Wait
```

thanks you.

Comment: So you want the `IdentifyingNumber` property value from the line where `Name` is `Teams Machine-Wide Installer`?

Comment: i want the IdentifyingNumber value (with the {} )

Comment: `$var1 = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name like '%team%'")[0].IdentifyingNumber` should do

Comment: what do the "[0].IdentifyingNumber" ?

i can't see the resultat of the output command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the Format-Table cmdlet. This "cosmetic" type cmdlet sends output (only) to the console, can't re-use it (output).
Lose that in the pipeline and it will work just fine, like so:

```
$obj = get-wmiobject Win32_Product -Filter "Name like '%team%'" | Sort-Object -Property Name

$var1 = $obj.IdentifyingNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick :

```
$guidapp = get-wmiobject Win32_Product -Filter "Name like '%teamviewer%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber


Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x $guidapp /quiet /n" -Wait
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Indeed, `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is another way to extract property values from command output. Given that Eduard's answer explains the primary problem with your original approach and provides an effective solution that answer your question _as asked_, I suggest accepting his answer.